# How to send text within a textarea having the attribute style="display: none;" through C# and Selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I need to write in the textarea with the simple sendkeys function in selenium.
This textarea (ID = 'txtSkillsTaught-Value') is followed by a script tag where the visibility of the textarea is hidden i guess due to which I am not able to write text.

tried the simple
    `driver.findelment(By.Id("txtSkillsTaught-Value")).sendkeys("text");`
even tried switching to the iframe above but didnt worked
attached the image of HTML code

thanks,
Amey[image]

Comment: share the same image in text format here. and what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Are you able to enter text manually? What are the steps to make the textbox visible?

Comment: yes i am able to enter the text manually

Comment: @Amey : What do you do manually to send something to text box ? The same can be automated.

Answer (score 1):

In one hand if it is not visible maybe is not a good idea put text inside... But, in the other hand I need made things like that sometimes. I usually change the visibility for this element before send the keys with a javascript execution in my selenium code (I use java but for C# should be more or less the same):

```
executeScript("$('.yui-button.yui-link-button').find(\"textarea[id='txtSkillsTaught-Value']\").css({'opacity':'1', 'visibility':'visible', 'display':'block', 'position':'relative', 'transform':'none'})");
driver.findelment(By.Id("txtSkillsTaught-Value")).sendkeys("text");
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have provided the `<textarea>` is out of the `<iframe>` but having the *attribute* **style="display: none;"**. So to send a character sequence to the `<textarea>` you can use the following solution:

```
IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//td[@class='t-editable-area']//textarea[@class='t-content t-raw-content' and @id='txtSkillsTaught-value']")));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", element);
element.SendKeys("Amey");
```